# Find and Replace from visible rows only

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this piece of code that finds and replaces some text. However, there is a filter applied to the sheet and I want the find and replace to work for visible rows only - is this possible?

```
function findAndReplaceText2() {
  const searchText = "Undergoing QA";
  const replaceText = "Check Status";
  const sheetName = "OpenCasesSummary";
  const rangeLoc = "I6:I1000"
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange(rangeLoc);
  range
    .createTextFinder(searchText)
    .replaceAllWith(replaceText)
}
```

The result I am after is that only those rows with 'Undergoing QA' in column I, that do NOT have 'QA Queue' in column C will be replaced with 'Check Status'.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in the current stage, TextFinder cannot be used to the filtered rows. But, I thought that your situation of `The result I am after is that only those rows with 'Undergoing QA' in column I, that do NOT have 'QA Queue' in column C will be replaced with 'Check Status'.` can be used. When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function findAndReplaceText2() {
  const searchText = "Undergoing QA";
  const replaceText = "Check Status";
  const sheetName = "OpenCasesSummary";
  const rangeLoc = "C6:I";
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange(rangeLoc + sheet.getLastRow());
  const values = range.getDisplayValues().map(([c, , , , , , i]) => [(!c && i == searchText) ? replaceText : i]);
  range.offset(0, 6, values.length, 1).setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, I thought that `The result I am after is that only those rows with 'Undergoing QA' in column I, that do NOT have 'QA Queue' in column C will be replaced with 'Check Status'.` might be able to be achieved.